# Saving multiple values in isolated storage

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 application. In my application, I have to store the scores of each attempt.

Eg:

1st attempt: orange 10 ,apple 20 ,mango 30.

2nd attempt: orange 5 ,apple 20 ,mango 25.

3rd attempt: orange 15 ,apple 25 ,mango 5.

and so on...

I have a score sheet where I need to show the values of each attempt.

This is how I am  trying to save the values:

**To write values**

```
try
            {
                using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(store.OpenFile(myObject.Title + "_State.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)))
                    {
                        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
                        serializer.Serialize(sw, myObject);
                        serializer = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
```

**To read**

```
MyObject myObject = null;
            try
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    // Read application settings. 
                    if (isoStore.FileExists((myObject.Title + "_State.xml"))
                    {
                        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                        {
                            using (StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(store.OpenFile((myObject.Title + "_State.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
                            {
                                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
                                myObject = (MyObject)serializer.Deserialize(SR);

                                serializer = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // If setting does not exists return default setting.
                        myObject = new MyObject();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return myObject;
```

But in the above code, every time the values are replaced instead of added to previous values.

How do I add the attempts and their values to the same file?

Answer (score 2):

Try to change [FileMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when writing to the file to `FileMode.Append` instead of `FileMode.Create` :

```
store.OpenFile(myObject.Title + "_State.xml", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)
```

About `FileMode.Append` from MSDN link above :

> "*Opens the file if it exists and seeks to the end of the file, or creates a new file. This requires FileIOPermissionAccess.Append permission. FileMode.Append can be used only in conjunction with FileAccess.Write. Trying to seek to a position before the end of the file throws an IOException exception, and any attempt to read fails and throws a NotSupportedException exception.*"

Comment: I have used this, and its able to write, but i am able to read it for first time, after that its shows me error System Exception in my Bean class